# What's the best pattern for iterating over maps of maps and deleting items?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I'm working on some code that basically does:

```
mapSize = map.size();
for(iter=map.begin;iter!=map.end();)
{
  call function which might delete a map item;
  if(map.size()==mapSize )
  {
     iter++;
  }
  else
  {
     mapSize = map.size();
     iter=map.begin(); /* Start again if something was deleted */
  }
}
```

I think there must be a better way to do this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

The function should return the next valid iterator for you. This is how the `map`'s normal `erase` function works.

Comment: The function can't take the iterator as a parameter or return it.  The function may delete one or more items from the map, not necessarily the current one.

Comment: Whoa! Your function does not use the iterator, your loop does not use the iterator. So why are you using an iterator here? Does your function return *anything* that might indicate that it is finished. e.g., `do { status = call_function(args); } while (status != finished);`

Comment: @David Hammen Because he wants to visit all of the elements in the map?  His function might take something like `iter->first` (the key) or `iter->value` as an argument.

Comment: @David Correct. The arguments to the function are all in the iterator.

Answer (score 2):

Map has the important property that inserting a new element into a map does not invalidate iterators that point to existing elements. Erasing an element from a map also does not invalidate any iterators, except, of course, for iterators that actually point to the element that is being erased.

EDIT

forgot the example

```
for(iter=map.begin;iter!=map.end();)
{
  map< type >::iterator itCopy( iter++ );

  // call function which might delete a map item;
  foo( itCopy );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be

- Only have maps of maps and not maps of pointer to maps
- Insert objects in them... or shared_ptr

This way the cleanup will be done automatically for you.

Comment: The question mentions neither map of pointers nor cleanup, but a regular case of filtering some stuff out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all calling map.size() may cost a lot, so don't use it too much.

```
for(iter=map.begin;iter!=map.end();)
{
  current_iter = iter;
 ++iter;
  // call function which might delete a map item;
  my_function(current_iter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a small consideration on your code. If you look at it in a functional way, I think you should rewrite it not to use an actual loop, but, maybe, an algorithmic function like `remove_if`, executed as many times as you need to process/delete all the needed elements. I think this leads to a much clearer code, not having to deal with explicit initialization of the for loop. For instance, in pure C++ (not lambda, not C++0x, that would make this easier):

```
template <typename I>
class Processor
{
    bool operator(I const& i)
    { // process, return true if it has to be removed
    }
};
```

and then, in your code:

```
std::remove_if(map.begin(), map.end(), Processor<Item_type>());
```

and have some kind of flag to spot when no element was removed, so you can continue (maybe an element of the `Processor` class).

Comment: I suggested something like this to the other guys here, but no-one has ever used this construct.  Don't you end up with loads of little classes littering the code?

Comment: Well, this is definitely the way to go. If they haven't used them, please, convince them to. Many classes? Maybe. You can parameterize them, or use plain functions local to the `.cpp` file. Then, you would just be separating what you're doing in different functions (not bad at all). Even more, if you don't want the functions, you can use things like `boost::lambda`, that don't force you to write a new function for this. But again, please, use this style. In the future you'll be glad.

Comment: @Neil: No, because you'll either use function (function pointer is a functor and can be made adaptable functor with `fun_ptr` wrapper) or local class (structs/classes can be declared inside functions including their inline methods).

Comment: You cannot use `std::remove_if` on an `std::map`, since it modifies the sequence (and you can't modify the elements in a map, at least not the key part).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what the question is: the title speaks of "maps of
maps", but I don't see any in the example code.

Other than that: what should occur if an item was deleted by the
function?  Do you want to restart the iteration from the start, or
continue where you left off (knowing that where you left off might have
been removed from the map)?  For the first, your code is basically
correct, and I don't think that there's a better solution; at least I
can't think of one off hand.  For the second, I think you'd want
something like:

```
iter = map.begin();
while ( iter != map.end() ) {
    key = iter->first;
    //  call function...
    iter = map.upper_bound( key );
}
```

This is probably the simplest solution.  `map.upper_bound` is `O(lg n)`,
however; if the map is large, this could be a problem.  Depending on the
implementation of `map` (and the frequency with which your function
removes elements), using `++` on the iterator if nothing has been
removed from the map might be faster.

Of course, if you can guarantee that the function in question never
deletes the element after the one you're at, you can increment the
iterator before calling the function.  The solution with `upper_bound`,
however, works unconditionally, regardless of what the function changes
in the map.

Comment: My original example had maps of maps, but I simplified the example.  The real code has nested maps of maps but uses the same pattern.

Answer (score -1):

One good thing to know is that prefixed operator `++` returns the previous value of the iterator (a copy) and bumps the current iterator to its next value. So the next code is very interesting in your case:

```
for (iter = map.begin(); iter != map.end(); )
{
  // call function which might delete the item
  your_function(++iter);

  // and... that's all !
}
```

This way your current iterator is not invalidated by the removal if you remove in your function via the `erase` falvor taking an iterator in parameter, and you're safe.

Comment: This will fail if the called function deletes the element behind the one the iterator originally pointed to.  (His question didn't say that the function might delete *the* item, but *a map item*.  The element the incremented iterator points to is "a map item".